# Reactjs: Can I access a ref in stateless component's event handler?

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know if it is possible to access a ref from a stateless components `onClick` handler?

For example:

```
function MyComponent ({myProp}) {
  var userFeedbackNode
  return <div>
    <textarea ref={(c) => userFeedbackNode = c}/>
    <button onClick={()=> {
       //do something with the userFeedbackNode here.
    }}>Send</button>
  </div>
}
```

I believe this method does work, but are there any issues with assigning and accessing refs this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**YES**. You can't attach ref to the functionnal component itself but you can get `ref` of the components inside (if they are not functionnal components themselves). You'll need to keep the variable reference outside the scope of the functionnal component itself, something like this :

```
let _inputRef

const MyComponent = (props) =>
    <input type=text  ref={ref  => typeof _inputRef == 'undefined' ? ref : _inputRef} />
```

So yes it's feasible but pretty useless since functionnal component do not have lifecycle methods  where you could potentially have the need to use that ref.